# match ... against on more field: give more importance to first field?

Tags: sql, mysql

I do a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM . WHERE MATCH(title,text) AGAINST ('word1') LIMIT 100
```

now of coure title is more important than text. Are there a way to tell mysql it should give more revelance if word1 is found in title than text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it but its seems a little clunky

```
SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT * FROM  WHERE 
MATCH(title) AGAINST ('word1') 
UNION
SELECT * FROM  WHERE 
MATCH(text) AGAINST ('word1') 

) t

LIMIT 100
```

Comment: @yes123. You can put in production. It would just be nice if there was a better way